# Create custom Consumer & Producer for an existing Component

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to extend the functionalities of an existing camel consumer/producer, and have the same camel component using the my implementation instead of the original consumer/producer.

Can this be done? If yes, how? Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just java code, so you can extend the classes and override the methods you want. And if really needed the source code is open so you can copy the old code if you need in your component.

But you may ask yourself why do you need to do this. Its much better to use the standard components as-is.

If you need a new feature then talk to the Apache Camel community about that, and see what can be added to the standard.
http://camel.apache.org/support.html